# How many ways can we place three guys and two girls on a line with 7 spaces given boys stay together and girls stay together?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, combinations

I am asked the following question:

> How many ways can we place three guys and two girls on a line with 7 spaces given boys stay together and girls stay together?

The textbook's answer is $144$ but for me it doesn't make much sense.

**My solution:**

The possibilities of distributing boys is $6$, girls is $2$ and the number of ways we can place the "empty spaces" between them is $4$ (two spaces at the right, one at the right and one in the middle of them and so on). Which leads to the answer $48$.

Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: You mean the pattern has to be $\_BBB\_GG\_$ or $\_GG\_BBB\_$?  Well, let's just count the first (same number for second).  The two blanks have three options so $(2,0,0),(0,2,0),(0,0,2),(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)$ so $6$ options.  Thus $6\times 6\times 2=72$.  So I'm getting $144$ total..not seeing the other factor of $2$.

Comment: Mmm I see. Actually lulu the answer is really 144, I typed the answer from another exercise, sorry about that.

Comment: As an alternate way to count, aside from the ordering within a single gender, we are just looking for permutations of $\{BBB,GG,X,X\}$ so $6\times 2\frac {4!}2=12\times 12=144$.

Comment: Oh, phew.  I was sure I had dropped a factor of $2$ somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You have $2$ ways for the disposition of the two groups boys/girls; $3!$ ways for the boys, $2!$ ways for the girls, and $\binom{4}{2}$ for the spaces. So the number of disposition is
$$
2\times3!\times2!\times\binom{4}{2}=144.
$$

I am missing a $2$ factor: are you sure that the text is correct?

Comment: You are right zar, I just edited my question. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I see now the other comments to te text. Very well, then.